# Player not rewinding 30 seconds in Chrome, but works in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, video, jwplayer

My code won’t work on Chrome, but works fine on Firefox. Instead of rewinding 30 seconds, as it is supposed to, it just pauses the player on Chrome. Any idea what I have set up wrong?

Here is the code that I have been using:

```
function jumpBySeconds(s) {
    try{playerInstance.seek(playerInstance.getPosition()+s);}catch(e){}
}

function displayButtons() {
    var playButton = document.getElementsByClassName('jw-controls jw-reset')[0];
    playButton.style.display = "block";
}

function hideButtons() {
    var playButton = document.getElementsByClassName('jw-controls jw-reset')[0];
    playButton.style.display = "none";
}

function addControlbarListeners(){
    var timer;
    var player = document.getElementsByClassName('jwplayer')[0];
    player.onmouseover = function(){displayButtons();};
    player.onmouseout = function(){hideButtons();};
    player.addEventListener("mousemove",function(){
        displayButtons();
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer=setTimeout(mouseStopped,2000);
    });

    function mouseStopped(){                              
        hideButtons();
    }
}

function addPlayForwardAndBackwardButtons(){
    var playBack = document.createElement("img");
    playBack.id = "-30sb";
    playBack.setAttribute('class','jw-icon jw-icon-display jw-button-color jumpBackward jw-reset');  
    playBack.onclick = function(){
        jumpBySeconds(-30);
    }

    var middleBar = document.getElementsByClassName('jw-display-icon-container jw-reset')[0];
    middleBar.appendChild(playBack);
    middleBar.setAttribute('style',"background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0); border: 0px; display: flex;");
    var playButton = middleBar.childNodes[1];
    middleBar.removeChild(playButton);
    middleBar.appendChild(playButton);

    var playForward = document.createElement("img");
    playForward.id = "+30sb";
    playForward.setAttribute('class','jw-icon jw-button-color jw-icon-display jw-reset jumpForward');
    playForward.onclick = function(){
        jumpBySeconds(30);
    }

    var middleBar = document.getElementsByClassName('jw-display-icon-container jw-reset')[0];  
    middleBar.appendChild(playForward);                    
    // set icon to center
    middleBar.style.width = "100%";
    middleBar.style.margin = "-1.0em auto 0";
}

playerInstance.onPause(function(){
    console.log("video stopped");
});

playerInstance.onPlay(function(){
    console.log("video playing...");
});

playerInstance.onReady(function(){            
    addPlayForwardAndBackwardButtons();
    addControlbarListeners();          
});
```

Comment: doesn't work **HOW**?

Comment: Instead of rewinding 30 sec like it suppose to (which it does on firefox) it just pauses the player on chrome

Comment: In chrome try it in a incognito window. (could be caching)

Comment: Is there any information in the browser's console?

Comment: I tried it in incognito window it still didnt work :(@NickJ

Comment: Just 
video playing...rewind5.php:98 
video stopped @JayBlanchard

Comment: Someone asked about this recently on the support forums - you may find this helpful: https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/questions/16284971-adding-fast-forward-and-rewind-controls-